# Explicitly Returning a value from a constructor in javascript

Tags: javascript, constructor, return-value

http://ejohn.org/blog/building-a-javascript-library/

In the above link John Resig Suggests calling and returning `new foo` in a constructor if the caller originally forgot to.

that makes some sense to me, but then I get a strict error because my constructor does not 'always' return a value. Upon gaining a little understanding of constructors in javascript, i stopped returning `this` because `new` automatically does that.

My question is, should I ...

1. Not use the defensive technique described?
2. return this at the end of my constructor?
3. Mystery option that I am ignorant of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

returning `this` is pointless because if the caller forgot to add `new` then `this` will be the document, not an instance of `foo`. What i usually do is start a constructor with `if(! (this instanceof foo)) return new foo();` or something to that effect

**Edit:** after a more careful read, if you want to avoid strict errors and you are doing this already, yes, `return this` at the end is usually a good idea

Comment: right, that is the suggestion that led me to the question. If I explicitly return during an error, I get a strict warning because i implicitly return when all goes well

Comment: yep, so returning this if all goes well is probably a good idea